# prometheus client custom metrics with timestamp not expiring

Tags: python, client, prometheus

I have written below custom collector which pulls the data from a rest api and adds page view metrics. Each payload has 5 metrics so I am adding timestamp to it. It successfully publishes it to the http listener but the metrics never expires. How can I add the expiry to these metrics?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import re
import sys
import time
import datetime
import urllib3
import requests
import aniso8601
import pytz
import json

from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY

class HttpCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "my_endpoint"
        self.username = 'my_userid'
        self.password = 'my_pass'
        self.labels = ['app_name', 'url_host' ]
        self.page_views_metrics = GaugeMetricFamily('pageviews', 'Page Views', labels=self.labels)

    def collect(self):
        headers = {'Accept': '*/*', }
        auth = (self.username, self.password)
        urllib3.disable_warnings()
        result = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, auth=auth, timeout=60, verify=False)
        if not result.ok:
            # Log error
            print("No results")
            return
        json_result = result.json()
        for record in json_result['records']:
            timestamp_epoch = covert_date_to_epoch(record["timestamp'])
            label_values = ["testapp", "testhost"]
            self.page_views_metrics.add_metric(label_values, record["page_views"], timestamp=timestamp_epoch)
        yield self.page_views_metrics
```

Comment: You probably try to misuse the Prometheus AFAIU.
Prometheus is used for monitoring, not for analytics. You should probably use Mixpanel/GA/Kinesis or some other tool like these.
I'm thinking about that because you're putting the timestamp as the label that will explode the cardinality of this metric.

Just don't put the timestamp as a label. What do you want to accomplish with that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using timestamp as the label. This kind of scenario is very well handled by InfluxDB. Initially Prometheus restricted the use of timestamp but now it allows it. So wanted to utilize that in my special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the self.page_views_metrics as local variable to collect method solved the problem.

```
import re
import sys
import time
import datetime
import urllib3
import requests
import aniso8601
import pytz
import json

from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY

class HttpCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "my_endpoint"
        self.username = 'my_userid'
        self.password = 'my_pass'
        self.labels = ['app_name', 'url_host' ]

    def collect(self):
        headers = {'Accept': '*/*', }
        auth = (self.username, self.password)
        urllib3.disable_warnings()
        result = requests.get(self.url, headers=headers, auth=auth, timeout=60, verify=False)
        if not result.ok:
            # Log error
            print("No results")
            return
        json_result = result.json()
        page_views_metrics = GaugeMetricFamily('pageviews', 'Page Views', labels=self.labels)
        for record in json_result['records']:
            timestamp_epoch = covert_date_to_epoch(record["timestamp'])
            label_values = ["testapp", "testhost"]
            page_views_metrics.add_metric(label_values, record["page_views"], timestamp=timestamp_epoch)
        yield page_views_metrics
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use self.page_views_metrics as a local variable? Please help me with this.

Comment: @user_123 setting it as local variable in collect() will reset its value in each collection. If used as class var, it never gets reset unless u reset it in each collection specifically